# shortcut doesn't work in PyQt5 in tray dropdown menu

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was trying to set a shortcut for dropdown menu. The code is below

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction

class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        super(SystemTrayIcon, self).__init__(icon, parent)
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)
        # add actions and shortcuts for them.
        exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(parent.close)
        menu.addAction(exitAction)

        restoreAction = QAction('Restore', self)
        restoreAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+R")
        restoreAction.triggered.connect(self.restore)
        menu.addAction(restoreAction)

        self.setContextMenu(menu)
    def restore(self):
        print 'restore'

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.tray_icon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('/opt/WizNote/wiznote.png'), self)
        self.tray_icon.show()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The shortcut doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my code? 
Python2.7 and PyQt5 was installed in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as yours, and I solved it by respecting the following pattern for each action:

```
menu.addAction(exitAction)
parent.addAction(exitAction)  # line to be added
```